# ВрУчат или вручАт?

Tags: фонетика

*И вам седло большое, ковер и телевизор —

Подарок сразу врУчат. А может быть, вручАт.*
А как же все-таки правильно?)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Правильный вариант — *"вруча́т"*.